# Round off Double to 2 decimal without changing the datatype

Tags: java

```
double value1 = 1000
double value2 = 2563.59
System.out.println("value1 ="+String.format("%.2f",value1));
System.out.println("value2 ="String.format("%.2f",value2));

Output 
value1 = 1000.00
value2 = 2563.60
```

This returns `1000.00` and `2563.60` but the type of output changes to string.

I want `1000.00` and `2563.60` as the output without changing the datatype.

Can anyone help me?

The dtatype must be double itself

Comment: The output is printed, so doesn't matter the type if it's String, int, double .. why "not change datatype" ?^^

Comment: `double value1 = 1000.00; double value2 = 2563.60;`?

Comment: Can it go "through" another datatype?

Comment: @azro : that was the requirement

Comment: @Viktor Mellgren  Yes it can go through, but should return double

Comment: @Fida but it has no sense, 2563.60 is not a double only a REPRESENTATION as a String, you can't, look at Sweeper answer, it's the nearer one

Comment: @azro what I am doing is getting the number from table and inserting it to excel using apache poi. There I want to calculate the sum.So I want to give the coming datas in the string to double so that they can get the sum

Comment: @azro  I knew its a representation, but I want 1000 as 1000.00 in double!! What should I do?

Comment: @Fida you seems to not understand ^^ 1000.00 is a String, like answer given below

Comment: @azro Thanks Now I understood

Comment: @Tom Actually I dont want to know how to round a number , but round a number without changing the datatype. thats what I want to know

Comment: And that's what the other answers are telling you.

Comment: @Tom No in that answers all the type will be in the form of string

Comment: The below answers all are giving me the datatype as string. Some are giving double but no .00 is there after whole numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `double` types store values, not strings. There are gonna be some cases where rounding it to 2 decimal places changes nothing. For example, the value `1`. If you do a `String.format` on `1`, it will become `1.00`. However, `1` and `1.00` are the same value, so turning `1` to 2 decimal places makes it `1` again. `double` thinks that `1` and `1.00` are the same value (I mean, they really *are*, it's just formatted differently).

Also note that double values are inaccurate. It might appear as though it is `1.23` but in reality it might be something like `1.2300000000000001`.

To correct a double to 2 d.p., all you have to do is to convert the formatted string back to a double:

```
String str = String.format("%.2f",value1));
double result = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `String.format(..)` if you don't want it to change to a string.

Please refer to [Decimal Format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
// 2 places of decimal
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat( "#.00" );

System.out.println(formatter.format(1.23));    // 1.23
System.out.println(formatter.format(1));       // 1.00
System.out.println(formatter.format(1.234));   // 1.23
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are using string.format in first place?

```
DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("##.00");
System.out.println(f.format(value1));
```

you need to import java.text.DecimalFormat; for this

Answer (score 0):

Using `BigDecimal.setScale()` and using rounding mode ceiling

```
    double value1 = 1000;
    double value2 = 2563.59;

    System.out.println("Before");
    System.out.println("value1 = " + value1);
    System.out.println("value2 = " + value2);

    value1 = BigDecimal.valueOf(value1).setScale(1, RoundingMode.CEILING).doubleValue();
    value2 = BigDecimal.valueOf(value2).setScale(1, RoundingMode.CEILING).doubleValue();

    System.out.println("After");
    System.out.println("value1 = " + value1);
    System.out.println("value2 = " + value2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In anything that uses limited-precision, binary floating-point numbers -- which is the default for Java and most programming languages -- the concept "number of decimal places" only ever applies to display. The internal binary representation has no concept of "decimal places" because the data is not decimal.

Consequently, the number of decimal places applies only to how data is displayed, and it is irrelevant what data types may be used to do the display.

When questions arise about rounding decimal numbers, it's often because the programmer has not fully understood how float-point math works.